# Setup CI Github Actions for hardhat project

Tags: contract-development, hardhat

I have an hardhat project and would like to add CI workflow using github actions.
Here is my github repository.
https://github.com/kimiro34/ens-registry-setup

`.github/workflow/main.yml` file looks like this

```yml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
env:
  NETWORK: $NETWORK
  RPC_URL_ZNX_TESTNET: $RPC_URL_ZNX_TESTNET
  RPC_URL_ZNX_MAINNET: $RPC_URL_ZNX_MAINNET
  MNEMONIC: $MNEMONIC
  ROPSTEN_URL: $ROPSTEN_URL
jobs:
  start-hardhat-node:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run node:start
      - run: npm run test
```

Here is my `package.json` file.

```json
{
  "name": "hardhat-project",
  "scripts": {
    "node:start": "npx hardhat node",
    "test": "npx hardhat test --network localhost",
    "ci": "scripts/test.sh",
    "compile": "npx hardhat compile",
    "deploy": "npx hardhat run --network deploy scripts/deploy.ts",
    "deploy:hardhat": "npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/deploy.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.0.3",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^7.2.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.47",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.2.0",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.6.2",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
    "solhint": "^3.3.7",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.7.20",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typechain": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.3",
    "@ensdomains/ens-contracts": "^0.0.11",
    "eth-ens-namehash": "^2.0.8"
  }
}
```

The problem is after running `npm run node:start` cmd `npm run test` never starts.
Here is the current status which I mean.
https://github.com/kimiro34/ens-registry-setup/actions
https://github.com/kimiro34/ens-registry-setup/runs/5870753222?check_suite_focus=true

I understand that this is because `npm run node:start` which runs 'npx hardhat node' and this runs  local blockchain which won't stop.

So it is possible to test my hardhat project using github action?

Comment: See how I do this in [prb-contracts](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-contracts/blob/main/.github/workflows/integration.yaml), and also see my [template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template).

Comment: Hello try to do the same but i don't really get how set up a Mnemonic for running test before a Merge Request.
I can't add a Mnemonic if my repo, any idea

Comment: You can use [GitHub Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) to add your mnemonic in a GitHub repo. Consider starting from my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template/blob/fe83b6cb1563abd5c2d29323b2bd1a3f3facad10/.github/workflows/ci.yml).

Answer (score 2):

You can run `node:start` and `deploy` commands concurrently.

Try the following:

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install packages
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      - run: yarn --ignore-scripts
        shell: bash
      - name: Create local node and deploy
        run: |
          yarn hardhat node &
          yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.ts --network localhost
      - name: Run Tests
        run: yarn hardhat test
```